# If your blog was an app on Facebook 

Tags: facebook, customization, user-interface

If you were to turn your blog into a Facebook app, what features would it have?  What would the UI look like?  What are the significant dealbreakers you'd need to satisfy to extend your blog to a social networking platform?

I'm marking this as a community wiki because I'm not looking for one answer, but for an array of "best practices" that developers should consider when taking their blog online through a social network.  One feature/UI element/dealbreaking necessity per answer please.

Comment: I am not sure how is this WP-related?.. Question seems to focus on another platform completely and applies to any blog in general.

Comment: For context - I am building a plug-in that allows you to deploy a WordPress blog as a Facebook application.  Unfortunately they featureset I would use and the featureset other bloggers would actually want are very different.  So the question could be, what WordPress features would you want to remain if your blog were being viewed on Facebook.

Comment: Also, I'm writing this from WordCamp Portland where we just had a long conversation about integrating WordPress-powered blogs with social network applications.

Comment: Why would you want this? As apposed to a fan page with details of your WP site? Seems to me that people are warey of apps that add little value, and I am unsure what value you can add to peoples Facebook feeds that facebook doesn't already provide.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My number 1 feature would be to have the ability to use WordPress to manage a fan page.

It would have to have the ability to use a WordPress page to create a Facebook page application tab.

Published posts would auto publish to the Facebook wall and comments would sync between WordPress and Facebook.

Comment: +1 for comments sync and you can manage your fan page with WordPress. Try this http://www.wp4fb.com/

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice to be able to manage your facebook "/pages/city/companyX" page from one WordPress install (instead of coding a seperate solution see e.g. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/tutorials/r-face/) this would enable customers (who all want to be on facebook) to have more or less one entry to manage things.

My number 1 feature would probably be statistics overview in the wordpress dashboard. So that the customer can check the progress of the internet strategy.

Comment: "So that the customer can check the progress of the internet strategy." +1